# How can I open a directory in the file-explorer app on Windows using git bash MINGW64 CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, git-bash, mingw-w64, explorer, microsoft-file-explorer

As a (former) [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) user, I was used to executing commands like

```
nautilus path/to/folder
```

or

```
pcmanfm path/to/folder
```

depending on the *file-explorer* app installed on my system.
This led to the result that the file-explorer was opened up in the directory of interest, which I called here for exemplary reasons `path/to/folder`.

Up until now, I could not figure out how to do the same on `Windows 10` using the `git bash` (MINGW64) - shell.

Comment: Does the following work?: `explorer \`cygpath -w path/to/folder\``

Comment: Yes, that actually works. I'd be nice to know whether there is a simpler way, such as `explorer path/to/folder`. I've elaborated more on that in my answer below.

Comment: Create a bash function?: `explore() { explorer \`cygpath -w $1\`; }` Then you can just type `explore path/to/folder`

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot @ssbssa !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @ssbssa,
I found 3 versions that worked for me using `/c/Users/username/Downloads/Test_files` as test-path:

```
$ explorer `cygpath -w "C:\Users\username\Downloads\Test_files"`

$ explorer `cygpath -w "/c/Users/username/Downloads/Test_files"`

$ explorer `cygpath -w /c/Users/username/Downloads/Test_files`
```

It is important to note that by employing quotes `".."` the command will be accepted no matter
which directory-separation type is implemented (`"/"` or `"\"` depending on your OS).
When leaving the quotes out, it'll work only with the linux-style `"/"`.

What's more, it is essential to wrap the `cygpath -w path/to/folder` - command into
a pair of *back-ticks* "", otherwise the entire command will open a default folder in your windows explorer instead of the target folder.
This is by the way (one of) the default fall-back behavior in case something goes wrong, as far as I've experienced it.

To be honest, I would love to know a way of doing the same thing just with a command like

```
$ explorer /c/Users/username/Downloads/Test_files
```

since otherwise it seems a bit unpractical to type this `cygpath -w ..` - wrapper around the command.

If you know a simplification of that, or an easier approach altogether, kindly let me know.

---

**EDIT - Solution found thanks to @ssbssa's comment:**

One can set a new `bash`-function in the `bash shell` via

```
explore() { explorer `cygpath -w $1`; }
```

Then, open the `Windows Explorer` in the folder of interest via

```
explore path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want the current directory to be opened, you can use

```bash
explorer "$(cygpath -w $(realpath .))"
```